# Why does data from .subscribe() first return an empty object before filling the object with data?

Tags: javascript, angular, for-loop, observable

I'm working with Observables to get data from the backend. In my function I'm subscribing to my observable and when I console.log() the data that is passed back it appears to return twice. First an empty object and then later the data I'm expecting.

This is causing a problem for me because I'm trying to use a for...in loop to compare the keys of the data with the keys of another object so I can match the values. I get a TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
because the data first returns an empty object. This is confusing to me because I'm doing console.log() inside the subscribe's callback method.

Isn't the whole point of the callback method to wait until the data has arrived?

I've tried a callback function as well as putting the for...in directly inside the subscribe and neither work because the object returns empty first. What am I doing wrong?

```
this.memberService.memberDetails.subscribe(member => {
    this.member = member;
    this.member_id = this.authService.loggedInUser.app_user_data.member_id;
    this.parseAddress();
    console.log('member subscribe', this.member);
    this.formData();
});
```

// UPDATE: MemberService code

```
 private _memberDetails = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

 public get memberDetails() {
    return this._memberDetails.asObservable();
}
```

// Notice the console.log() has fired twice

[image: notice the console.log() has fired twice]

```
formData() {
    for (const flatProfileKey in this.profileData['permanent_address'][0]) {
        for (const key in this.member['addresses'][0]) {

            if (flatProfileKey === key) {
                this.profileData[key] = this.flatProfile[key];
                console.log('profileData perament_address', this.profileData['permanent_address'][0])

            }
        }

    }
}
```

// If I try to loop through the data it returns an undefined error presumably because the subscribe first returns an empty object so there is nothing to loop through

[image: If I try to loop through the data it returns an undefined error presumably because the subscribe first returns an empty object so there is nothing to loop through]

Comment: Please share your `memberService` code where you have `memberDetails` setup. Alternatively, you can use the `filter` rxjs operator to filter undesired data.

Comment: Please see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected as you are setting initial value to `BehaviorSubject` to empty object here:

```
private _memberDetails = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
```

If you don't need an initial value you can consider using `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`.
Read more about `BehaviorSubject` here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected.

> Behavior subject will re-emit the last emitted value or the default value if no previous value has been emitted.

Now, see that you are providing the default value to the `BehaviorSubject` as an empty object. Since you are passing a default value to it, it will emit this default value to all the subscribers.

And when you retrieve the data and change the value of the `BehaviorSubject` then again it will emit the new data to the subscribers.

Also, if you are thinking to pass nothing as a default value to `BehaviourSubject`, you cannot do that.

Here, you have two options you can do:

1. You can add an additional `if` to check if the value emitted is default value `{}` or not. And according to that you handle the stuff. Here's the code:

   ```
   formData() { 
       if(this.profileData['permanent_address']) {
           // Data fetched, do something
           for (const flatProfileKey in this.profileData['permanent_address'][0]) { 

           } 
       }
       else {
           // If data is not fetched, do something if you want to
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject` that doesn't need a default value. Since it doesn't have a value, it will not emit it before fetching the data. Just change below line:

   ```
   private _memberDetails = new BehaviorSubject<any>({})
   ```

   to

   ```
   private _memberDetails = new Subject<any>()
   ```

   And this will work as you expect it to work.

Hope this helps.